# Listbox Resource Windows 10 universal

Tags: c#, listbox

i wanted to test the listbox xaml item. 
I created a Listbox and a .cs Class called "Mitarbeiter".

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;


    public class Mitarbeiter

 {
public int Age { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
List<Mitarbeiter> berater = new List<Mitarbeiter>
{
    new Mitarbeiter(13,"name1"),
    new Mitarbeiter(18,"name2")
};


public Mitarbeiter(int inputage, string inputname)
{
    Age = inputage;
    inputname = Name;
}

   }
```

Now i want to bind my listbox to the objects of the "berater" list and it should display the two "mitarbeiter" objects in the list.
Im a beginner and dont have so much experience so every code you write in your answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the XAML-file you have a ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" />
```

and in the cs-file you write

```
Mitarbeiter m = new Mitarbeiter();
myListBox.ItemsSource = m.berater;
```

In the Mitarbeiter-class override the **ToString()**, to display the name of the Mitarbeiter in the listbox.

```
public override String ToString()
{
    return Name;
}
```

Here is a good tutorial: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/